# Ethernet not working in 18.04. Wi-fi stops working after some time

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, ethernet

I have searched a lot for this, but haven't found a solution yet! Here are some relevant command outputs:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e0:db:55:ba:d8:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 196  bytes 39618 (39.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3635  bytes 379737 (379.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3635  bytes 379737 (379.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d24c:daf:8b52:1424  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:8b:fd:f2:d8:cf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13068  bytes 7854493 (7.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12937  bytes 1966814 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
$
```

As you can see, no inet address (I have disabled IPV6 based on suggestions somewhere. Previously, I was sometimes getting an inet6 addr).
The link, however, is detected. Here is the output from ethtool:

```
$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: yes
$
```

Here is the hardware information:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 73
       serial: 0c:8b:fd:f2:d8:cf
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-30-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:48 memory:e3500000-e3501fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
       logical name: eth0
       version: 12
       serial: e0:db:55:ba:d8:2f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:e3404000-e3404fff memory:e3400000-e3403fff
$
```

I see that driver r8169 is loaded (and not r8168 as many others who have problem with this card), but I don't see its package installed. Not sure if this is expected. Should I try to install it? Haven't tried that as I didn't want to break things further.

```
$ lsmod | grep r8 
r8169                  86016  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
$ dpkg -l | grep r8
$
```

I tried adding eth0 to /etc/networking/interfaces with

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and then 
    sudo ifdown eth0 ; sudo ifup eth0
However, I am not getting an IP address. Only getting "DHCPDISCOVER" lines for a long time:

```
$ sudo ifup eth0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:ba:d8:2f
Sending on   LPF/eth0/e0:db:55:ba:d8:2f
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0xc4c52e42)
```

I am using a dual boot PC with Windows 10. However, I haven't booted in Windows 10 in a while, and the router as well as my laptop was restarted several times after my last boot into Windows 10.

Everything was working fine till last week when I upgraded from 16.04 LTS to 18.04.1 LTS. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. So the problem was solved. Here is what I did for the ethernet connection:

In file /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf, I changed

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

to

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

After this, I executed

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

and ethernet started working automatically!

In case of the wifi, my NetworkManager seemed to think it was hardware disabled (after working for a few hours). I use a Dell Inspiron 7537, and don't have any hardware switch. I tried rfkill to see if it was a soft block:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I found out that there is an "Airplane mode" button on my keyboard. Once I pressed that, wifi started working! I am not sure why this was registered as a hard block and not a soft one though. rfkill output after this:

```
$ rfkill list all
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Apparently, my bluetooth was also disabled earlier!